# checking whether a particular element exists or not in a c++ STL vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

I wanted to check whether an element exist at a particular vector location, say i, before accessing it like v[i]. Could you let me know how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm very confused.  You have to access the vector in order to find out if an element exists.  So how do you determine if an element exists at position i without accessing the vector?  Use another vector?

Comment: Accessing the vector is obviously OK, but calling `operator[]` with unchecked arguments ("like v[i]") isn't.

Answer (score 9):

```
if (0 <= i  &&  i < v.size()) {
  // OK
  std::cout << v[i]; // Example
} else {
  // Wrong
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how the size of a vector can be used to find out if an element in the vector exists?  Given a vector of 500 elements, how does the `size` method help me determine if element at position 10 exists?

Comment: I think the question means "how to find if there is an element (or any value) at the position indexed by i"

Comment: @Thomas, size() returns the number of elements actually in the vector. so v[n] where 0 <= n < size() must contain an element.

Answer (score 4):

An element is guaranteed to exist at every position `i` where `i >= 0` and `i < v.size()` as vectors are contiguous sequences of elements and "holes" are not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `v.size()`.

Comment: I know how, but I guess that your answer won't help the questioner. Use how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if an element exists in a vector, the quickest method is to sort the array then use a search method such as binary search.

If this action is performed many times, perhaps changing the data structure will yield better performance.  An std::map is good for this, and if your compiler has one, use a hash table or map.

Otherwise the only way to determine if a value exists in an vector without accessing the vector is to use a second data structure to remember the value and position.

Comment: This may or may not be quicker. A linear search may well be much quicker than sorting if the search is only performed once per sort.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a `std::vector` preallocated at a specific dimension, let's say `n`, and you want to see if the element at index `i` (`i < n`) was initialized or is just allocated.

Like @Thomas Matthews said, you can use a second data structure, a simple `bool[n]`, in which, at index `k`, you store `true` if the element at index `k` in your `vector` exists and `false` otherwise.

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5
v = [ *   *   * * ]

             0     1      2     3     4     5
exists = [ true, false, true, false, true, true ]
```